# "Analytic continuation" of function of two real variables

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

Consider the two situations

- (A) If I have a real analytic function $f(x)$ of real $x$, the series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(z-x_0)^n}{n!}f^{(n)}(x_0)$$

gives an analytic continuation of $f(x)$ in the complex plane in the neighbourhood of $x_0$.

- (B) If I have a real function of two real variables, I can regard it has a function $f(z,\bar z)$ of $z=x+iy$ and its conjugate. Then form the series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(z-z_0)^n}{n!}\partial^n_z f(z,\bar z)|_{z=z_0,\bar z=\bar z_0}.$$

(B) includes (A) as a special case when $f(z,\bar z)$ depends only on $x$.

> **My question is:** In (B) what is the relation of the resulting analytic function (if it exists) to the original function? And where can I read about this (assuming it's a respectable construction)?

**Edit:** A not very exciting but presumably correct viewpoint is that the original function can be viewed as an analytic function in $\mathbb{C}^2$ where $z$ and $\bar z$ are taken to be independent complex variables. The expression in (B) is then the restriction to the surface $\bar z=\bar z_0$, which is of course different from the original function defined on $z=\bar z$.